# ACF fields ,select where a email goes,apply conditional logic

Tags: wordpress, forms, email, advanced-custom-fields

I have pages with ACF(advanced custom fields) setup with different fields.
I want to be able to access that data and apply a 
conditional logic.
To apply the conditional logic there will be a contact form 
where the public will fill in and dependant on what they choose
an email will be sent out to different recipients.

Fields are:
Destination: of which there are 5 to choose from

type of place: house, apartment ( drop down)

email address: "email"

*Contact form will have*

```
    name:  
    Phone:  
    email address:  
    Destination:   (acf) select which ones  
    type of place (acf) selct which ones  
    Date picker  
    how many people  Adult  Children   
    Accommodation  package (select or both)  
    message
```

So from the 3 fields... destination, type of place and email 
I want an email to go to the email recipients who meet the criteria selected
with all of the mentioned above data to be sent.
with a default email sent to the wp account.

What is the best way to tackle this?

Comment: you could use the WP_mail function for this : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Comment: basically : `wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );`

Answer (score 0):

You have here 2 solutions :

First one, the easiest, you create 5 contact form, and depending on the acf value, you print the corresponding contact form. This solution might not been really beautiful, but is working well.

Seconde solution, a little bit harder, would be to add an input hidden in your form. Set the recipient email into this input hidden. Then hook, in your `function.php` the `wpcf7_before_send_mail()` hook. During this hook, replace the recipient mail set in CF7 to the one set in input hidden.